# Microsoft USD - Opening a third party application in USD Tab through CRM Page button click

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016, unified-service-desk

I have two questions here. I am using Microsoft USD 4.0 with CRM v9 and I am in a scenario where I want to open a third party desktop application within USD tab.

Now, opening the application is USD tab is not so difficult but what I want to do is open that application by push of a button inside a CRM page that is already opened inside USD.

So the scenario is like below,

> 1) We have a CRM Page opened inside USD.
>
> 2) Once user push a button inside that CRM Page a new tab will open.
>
> 3) The tab will be opened inside USD after we push the button inside
>   CRM page.

The other question is,

We are also in the stage of developing the third party application. So what points should we keep in mind to make it compatible with USD?

Answer (score 1):

One of the most commonly used way of opening a tab in USD from a button click in CRM page is to trigger an USD event from JavaScript tagged to the button click.

1. Create an event in USD, for the hosted control associated with the CRM page.
2. Trigger the same event from JavaScript something like below,

   window.open("http://event/?eventname=YourEventName);
3. Make sure you check for window.IsUSD before executing this part of code within JavaScript.
4. Once this event call is added to the JavaScript, you will get that triggered in USD on button click of CRM page.
5. Once you can track the event in USD, you should be knowing how to take it forward by adding action calls under the event which got triggered.

Hope that helps. Let us know if you have any queries regarding the same.